# Android Edittext Visible Characters but no AutoCompletion

Tags: android, passwords, android-edittext

I'm having an EditText which is a password field. Now I want to build a checkbox so that the user can decide if he wants to see the password with ***** or in plain text.
Therefore I built

```
if (passwordShouldBeVisible) {
        etext_key1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    } else {
        etext_key1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }
```

This works great but has the issue that if the password is plain the auto completion of the keyboard trys to help you.
Is there a chance to fix this?

Best regards,

Till

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `eText_key1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);`

Alternatively you can put the following in the XML definition of the EditText: `android:inputType="textFilter"`.

EDIT:

Here's an example, just make sure you are defining the settings in your toggle logic and your xml layout, or initializing the input type in your onCreate:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.edittext);

    Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switchbutton);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (passwordShouldBeVisible) {
                editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                        | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
            } else {
                editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD
                        | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                        | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
            }
        }
    });
```

and here's the XML file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|textFilter"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/switchbutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work for my HTC Desire :-(. I just or'd those two: `etext_key1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);`

Comment: Strange... I added an example that works on my device. Check that you are setting the input type both initially and when you switch it.

Comment: Just tried it again. The virtual emulator corretly deactivates the autocompletion while the real Desire trys to correct my input. :-( Any further ideas?

Comment: Are you using a custom soft keyboard? Perhaps this option only works with the default

Comment: No, Default keyboard of HTC Sense

Comment: Well there you go, the Sense UI has a custom soft keyboard, not default Google soft keyboard. Try using `eText.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
    | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER);` and see if that works

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am late, but I think clearest solution:

```
EditText t =  ...;//here find your input
t.setInputType(t.getInputType() ^ EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Here you just bitwise switch flag for password input, so other flags (mayber number input, etc) are untouched.